# How to select all the data from a table in which the data from another table is something having foreign key in another table

Tags: java, mysql, sql, swing, jdbc

So in my database, my tables are like this:[My tables in my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zec2L.png). So I have one too many relations in which 1 course can have many modules. So in my java module JTable, I want to show only those module data which courseName courseStatus is open and discard those data that are canceled.
So I tried:
`SELECT * FROM modules WHERE coursesName.courseStatus = 'Open'`.But it seems this does not work so how can I check using the foreign key `courseName` that I have set up in my modules table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like :

```
Select * FROM modules m, courses c WHERE c.courseName=m.courseName and c.courseStatus = 'Open'
```

or

```
Select * FROM modules m
join courses c on c.courseName=m.courseName
WHERE c.courseStatus = 'Open'
```

Comment: thanks i been trying to find the answer for sometime and did not find it.It worked.

Comment: And note that we stopped writing queries this way circa 1992